# Should I switch to a different opening?

Tags: opening, learning, queens-gambit

I have been using the queen's pawn game, Chigorin variation ever since I started chess. I am in my school's chess club now and my teacher tells me to use the queen's gambit instead. I know that the engine does not like the Chigorin variation, but I believe I am quite good at it.

What are the arguments for and against changing my opening?

Comment: The more openings you know and play, the harder it is for your proponent to prepare against you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am in my school's chess club now and my teacher tells me to use the queen's gambit instead

The fact that you are in your school's chess club changes the answer somewhat. It means you are young and still learning.

You have already invested work over time to get to know the Chigorin. You know the opening moves, you know the middlegame plans, you are familiar with the positions that arise. It is a sound opening (so not like the Grob). That means that you shouldn't abandon it for the Queen's Gambit.

As you are young and still learning it is worth your while to also learn the Queen's Gambit. The ideas and plans are different to the Chigorin but it is a useful opening to know and the different plans will expose you to new ideas for you which will help you improve overall.

So, don't switch completely, but do learn the new opening and play it regularly. At the same time go back some of the time to your Chigorin. It will make you a more difficult opponent. Your opponents won't know for sure what you are going to play and will find it harder to prepare against you.

Comment: @BillyIstiak  The page you linked to has it wrong. 1.d4 d5 2.Nc3 is the Richter Opening; 1.d4 d5 2.Nc3 Nf6 3.Bg6 is the Richter-Ver2sov. The Chigorin Defense to the Queen's Gambit is 1.d4 d5 2.c4 Nc6. There are Chigorin Variations in the French Defense and the Ruy Lopez (Spanish Game) and maybe others.